# cypress elm[aelFn] is not a function error in afterAll test hook

Tags: angular, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm using `cypress 9.3.1` with `@cypress/code-coverage 3.9.12` and `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor 4.3.1` in an angular `13.0.1` application.

My tests are running fine and also the code coverage is collected, but in the afterAll hook I get an error `TypeError: elm[aelFn] is not a function`. I have no idea where it is coming from.

I am using `ngx-build-plus 13.0.1` to serve the angular app with an extraWebpackConf, but even if I use the 'regular' `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` the error message appears at the end of my tests (the code is not instrumented then).

My `plugin/index.ts`:

```
const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
const path = require('path');

export default (on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): Cypress.PluginConfigOptions => {
  // code coverage plugin
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);

  // cucumber plugin
  const options = {
    ...browserify.defaultOptions,
    typescript: path.resolve('node_modules/typescript'),
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));

  return config;
};
```

You can see a screenshot of the error below:

[[image: elm[aelFn] is not a function1]

EDIT: even when I remove the cypress code coverage plugin the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix the issue, but when I catch the error it shows me less error messages at least

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (e) => {
  if (e.message.includes('elm[aelFn] is not a function')) {
    // we expected this error, so let's ignore it
    // and let the test continue
    return false;
  }
  // on any other error message the test fails
});
```

Comment: I'm new to Cypress. Which file do we put the Cypress.on in?

Comment: I have this issue as well, do you happen to use Ionic?

Comment: If you use Ionic this line is the one that errors out: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/8a9db8c9496be6c872376caa27ed04272afdc6d4/packages/angular/src/app-initialize.ts#L30
No idea why